# Python strptime not parsing data from imported CSV

Tags: python, django, strptime

I am attempting to import a CSV with lines that include a "created_at" date. I am getting circular errors.

The date string I am currently attempting to import is '2020-05-14 16:10:21.360520+00:00' which is on line[2] in my csv file.

Here is the code that I am attempting to use:

```
for line in import_csv:
    if line:
        import_data = BlogLink()
        created_at = line[2].split('.')
        import_data.created_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(created_at[0], "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")
```

this gives me the error:

```
time data '2020-05-14 16:10:21' does not match format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

My alternate for this code is this:

```
for line in import_csv:
    if line:
        import_data = BlogLink()
        created_at = line[2].split('.')
        import_data.created_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(created_at[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

This gives me the error:

```
time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

(ie it does not even attempt to include the time data). 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hmm... if `x = '2020-05-14 16:10:21.360520+00:00'.split('.')` then `datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` gives me a sane `datetime` object. I notice the `for` loop, so are there entries in the CSV file with an empty `line[2]` ?

Comment: My suspicion is that your second version is correct and doesn't give an error with line 2, but there is another non-empty line afterwards that causes the error message. My advise is to print out `created_at` in the loop before you create the date object.

Comment: That's it, thank you, there was a last_edited following up that wasn't working. I wasn't parsing out that they were failing for different reasons. Sorry, I had to drop my whole database earlier and I'm trying to repopulate it from spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

PEBCAK here. My problem was a follow-up line for import_data.last_edited had blank lines for objects that had not been edited. I've patched the code to skip when that field is empty.

```
for line in import_csv:
    if line:
        import_data = BlogLink()
        import_data.description = line[0]
        import_data.link = line[1]
        import_data.created_by = request.user
        import_data.created_at = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[2], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
        if line[3]:
            import_data.last_edited = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[3], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
        else:
            import_data.last_edited = None
        import_data.save()
```

is the working code.